# ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion: returning nil error and granted as NO

Tags: ios, facebook, acaccount, acaccountstore

I'm trying to test sign-in with `ACAccountStore`, however it isn't going very well.

I'm trying to gain access to the account like so:

```
ACAccountStore *store = [ACAccountStore new];

ACAccountType *accountType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey:@"12345678987654",
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey:@[@"email"]
                          };

[store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                               options:options
                            completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Access Granted: %d", granted);
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

However, my output looks like this:

```
2013-09-30 16:58:08.084 Application[1009:1103] Access Granted: 0
2013-09-30 16:58:08.090 Application[1009:1103] Error: (null)
```

I've ensured that my "Bundle ID" on the developers.facebook site and my application's `Bundle Identifier` match. I have also set "Sandbox Mode" to enabled. That's all that is required of me, right? What is going wrong?

Also, just to give some more information about the application, this application is bare bones. It's an empty application with one view controller that shows a button with one target that runs the code that I have written above. That is all there is to the application.

Comment: Is the account that's logged in on the iPhone an admin/developer/tester of your app? If you have sandbox mode "enabled", then only users with those roles can log in.

Comment: @MingLi Yes. I am the Admin and also doing the majority of the testing. Thank you for the idea, though.

Comment: Have you disallowed permissions once? You can check by going through Settings -> Facebook ... then look for your app there. If permission is not granted and there's no error, it means a user would have explicitly disallowed it either by tapping "Don't allow" in the permission dialog or via the aforementioned settings panel.

Answer (score 0):

Check developer.facebook.com to see if your app is sandboxed. Granted will be NO if your app is sandboxed and your are testing with another facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably have to do is to go to developers.facebook.com

Go to "Apps" tab and select your app. It is possible that you have to add the iOS platform to your app. So go to settings and click on "Add a platform". Select iOS and write the app bundle id. Check that the bundle is the same.

EDIT: Also you can print the error that returns. Maybe you are requesting for invalid permissions or permissions that you are not allowed to retrieve. Check this in "Status and Review" tab.

[image: setting iOS app on Facebook]

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/